# Does "Full Disk Access” include access to "Files and Folders" Privacy settings?

Tags: permission, privacy

In MacOS 10.15 new settings have been introduced in Security & Privacy that allow the user to determine access to files and folders for specific applications. 
For example access to the 'Desktop' or 'Downloads' folder can now be controlled but also 'Network Volumes' and 'Removable Volumes'.

Is granting 'Full Disk Access' to a process / application sufficient and includes the newer more specific permissions in Catalina for "Files and Folders"?

[image]

Comment: The answers below suggest that Full Disk Access should be enough for the app to access external drives, but currently (Feb 2021, Big Sur 11.2.1), this is not necessarily the case.  See e.g. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124185.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System Preferences screen is a bit vague (it says "*Allows specified apps access to data like Mail, Messages, Safari, Home, Time Machine backups, and certain administrative settings for all users on this Mac.*")

However the Apple developer documentation is more explicit - it says *Full Disk Access* (SystemPolicyAllFiles) covers **all** protected file locations including the new ones you mention.  From [PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl.Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol/services) :

> **SystemPolicyAllFiles** Allows the application access to all protected files, including system administration files.

More fine-grained file locations are listed in the link, including those you asked about.  Specifically :

> **SystemPolicyDesktopFolder** Allows the application to access files in the user's Documents folder.
>
> **SystemPolicyDocumentsFolder** Allows the application to access files in the user's Downloads folder.
>
> **SystemPolicyNetworkVolumes** Allows the application to access files on network volumes.
>
> **SystemPolicyRemovableVolumes** Allows the application to access files on removable volumes.

Note that [PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol) says "*In the case of conflicting specifications, the most restrictive setting (deny) is used*" but it doesn't seem to be possible to grant *Full Disk Access* and revoke another permission in *Files and Folders* through System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm left a little confused. It looks like you've missed "SystemPolicyDownloadsFolder" and attributed it's would-be description to "SystemPolicyDocumentsFolder" and given that description to "SystemPolicyDesktopFolder". Nonetheless, it's easy enough to decipher :)

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the expert on the matter, Quinn “The Eskimo!” from Apple Developer Relations / Developer Technical Support:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124895

> There are two further levels of protection in play here:
>
> - On 10.15 and later, certain common locations, like the Desktop, require **Files and Folders** access (see System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders).
> - On 10.14 and later, certain obscure locations, like the mail database, require **Full Disk Access** (see System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access).
>
> **The latter subsumes the former.**
>
> These privileges can only be granted by the user.

So 'Full Disk Access' *does* give access to the 'Files and Folders' locations as well.