# what is the file path to the photos app via terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, photos

I had a quick question regarding the file path of photos app. I am trying to run a bash/AppleScript script that accesses my photos app via terminal and uses the ls command to print all the file names to a .txt document though I can't seem to find the right file path chatgpt keeps giving me the following "/Users/alekburt/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters" but that doesn't seemed to be recognized any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you me$an the path to the app or to the actual photos which is the data the App uses? If the latter then in the app goto Settings and the first entry is Library Location.

Comment: hmm good question I don't really know which ever would allow me to print all the filenames to a .txt document which I would assume would be the latter?

Comment: Also know that chatGPT does not give accurate answers

Comment: Probaly then ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary - but they are all stored in a hased database so not much use.

Comment: STart with not how to do something but explain what you are trying to do

Comment: noted, ill give that a shot.

Comment: "but they are all stored in a hased database so not much use." are you saying this isn't really possible?

Comment: With recent versions of Photos, pictures are indeed not stored using their name. What do you want to do with the text file once you have it generated?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We're set up for the case where  a quick question often is precisely the opposite!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different. You may be asking the wrong question so I'll put up an answer in hopes it helps you with an answer. [This whole topic might belong on meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/527/5472) since you're asking what [appears to be an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/165931).

Rather than describe what you want to do - perhaps you wish to iterate over photos to gather statistics on which are new or perhaps perform some action on some or all of them. Instead of that you are asking about the first step you think will help you solve it - "can I enumerate the photos on the filesystem using `ls`"?

But - let's get you an answer. The Photos app uses a [somewhat complicated database schema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/418195/5472) to store the filesystem locations (and names of images, faces, metadata, etc...) of photos and identify them. You will need the `sqlite3` command and to de-obfuscate the hashes and table structure for most recent versions of the app.

The database is stored in ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary but [using those database files is not easy (to me at least).](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387121/5472)

Also, images are stored in multiple resolutions with machine-generated names - not picture0001.heic or whatever you might expect when you export an image. The "one image" has multiple manifestations - thumbnails, edited, original, limited resolution, full resolution - so your process/tool/script will need to contemplate and decide which if any of these are needed. Not all photos will be resident locally as well if you are using iCloud to host the authoritative copy of the pictures.

So, your problem might be solved much easier if you used a tool like Automator to export the photos to the filesystem and then use tools like `ls` to do your operations.

Comment: okay, wow I wasn't aware of the intricacies of this, ill re-evaluate my approach do you think AppleScript alone would be a better option?

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon you are missing the point - the solution might not be complex - but please explain what you are trying to do from first principles as if to someone who just uses Photos and has no idea about anything except the app.

Comment: im trying to get a .txt list of every file name currently in my photos app

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon We understand that. What do you intend to do with the list afterwards (there might be other ways to accomplish this, without creating a list first)?

Comment: No @AlekNaomieBurtPilon You will want to get the photos out of Photos app entirely unless you are up for a very large programming challenge.